# C++ initialize and fill 2D array with variable

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, fill

I have wrote code to store values in 2D array, as following format, and it works fine.

```
//Create array
double MyPoints[25][3] = {{4,3,1},{6,4,1},{7,3,1},{7,6,1},{6,7.5,1},{3,6,1},{4,5,2},{5,6.5,2},{6,9,2},{3.5,8,2},{6,5,3},{6,6,3},{9,4,3},{9,5,3},{8,4,4},{9.5,3,4},{10,4,4},{11,6,4},{9,6,4},{8,7,5},{10,7,5},{11,9,5},{8,10,5}} ;
cout << "Array Filled" << endl;

// Print Array
    for (int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
        {
            cout << MyPoints [c][d] << " Hellow ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

BUT I want to store the array values in variable, then assign variable (which hold array values inside) to fill the MyPoints array, it doesn’t work!!.

```
String MyVar = {{4,3,1},{6,4,1},{7,3,1},{7,6,1},{6,7.5,1},{3,6,1},{4,5,2},{5,6.5,2},{6,9,2},{3.5,8,2},{6,5,3},{6,6,3},{9,4,3},{9,5,3},{8,4,4},{9.5,3,4},{10,4,4},{11,6,4},{9,6,4},{8,7,5},{10,7,5},{11,9,5},{8,10,5}} ;

double MyPoints [25][3] = MyVar ;
cout << "Array Filled" << endl;
```

What I’m doing wrong? How to correct it.

Comment: No such thing as a `String` type in standard C++. Can you please clarify what is it you are trying to achieve? Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Why do you want to have a separate variable? Braced initializer lists don't have a type, so the only way for this to work is if `MyVar` is a 2d array, but then you don't need `MyPoints` anymore...

Comment: I need MyVar, Cause the text is not static as I wrote, but this text "{{4,3,1},{6,4,1},{7,3,1},{7,6,1},{6,7.5,1},{3,6,1},{4,5,2},{5,6.5,2},{6,9,2},{3.5,8,2},{6,5,3},{6,6,3},{9,4,3},{9,5,3},{8,4,4},{9.5,3,4},{10,4,4},{11,6,4},{9,6,4},{8,7,5},{10,7,5},{11,9,5},{8,10,5}} ;
"  Generated from another code.

Comment: Also to solve my problem in other way, How to fill the 2D array with set of values? any link or sample for filling the array with "for Loop" would be appreciated . I want to fill array with FOR .. LOOP

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double MyPoints[25][3] = {{
        0,
    }};

    std::string text = "{4,3,1},{6,4,1},{7,3,1},{7,6,1},{6,7.5,1},{3,6,1},{4,5,2},{5,6.5,2},{6,9,2},{3.5,8,2},{6,5,3},{6,6,3},{9,4,3},{9,5,3},{8,4,4},{9.5,3,4},{10,4,4},{11,6,4},{9,6,4},{8,7,5},{10,7,5},{11,9,5},{8,10,5}";


    for (int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
    {
        std::sscanf(text.c_str(), "{%lf,%lf,%lf},", &MyPoints[c][0], &MyPoints[c][1], &MyPoints[c][2]);
        text = text.substr(text.find("},") + 2);
    }
    // Print Array
    for (int c = 0; c < 25; c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0; d < 3; d++)
            std::cout << MyPoints[c][d] << " Hellow ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Code without using regex or stringstream(Almost C, not C++). You can also modify values of 2D array by `std::cin >> M[x][y]` or `M[x][y]=value`.

Comment: HJ S .. why  use "{%lf,%lf,%lf}," ?

Comment: You can find scanf syntax [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). I prefer `>>` to `scanf`/`sscanf` in C++, but scanf/printf is easy tool handling formatted string.